# how to open a popup at the bottom, above another View in Android?

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

In my Android App I have a view and on it a pop-up is opened at certain conditions.

How can I set it's position to be at the bottom? (anyhow above the other view).

Today's code just deals with Visibility 'gone' or 'hide'.

This is the popUp Xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/alerterLayout"
    android:layout_width="248dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
    android:background="@drawable/popup_alerter_base"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:padding="0dp">

    <!--
    ========================================================================
    * Title Text
    =======================================================================
    -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/alerterTitleLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about using [PopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html), you can use `showAtLocation(View v, int gravity, int x, int y)` to get it in the desired spot with respect to whichever `View` you want.

You can play with the `params` to get the exact result you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can take the layout inside the same xml file as in which you have defined your view, on top of which you need to show the pop-up. Then you can try to make the pop-up layout visible and invisible whenever you want to. Keep the initial visibility of Pop-up layout as GONE.

Comment: I would appreciate if I get a comment why my answer was down-voted, so that I can also know what was wrong in my answer. Thanks!!!