# Show popup window from another class Android

Tags: android, class, android-activity, popup, android-popupwindow

I have an activity and a class that implements a popup window. Using [this](http://mrbool.com/how-to-implement-popup-window-in-android/28285) tutorial I implemented the popup. I call the methods init() and popupInit() from the activity and everything else is in the class. My problem is that the popup does not show.

Here is the popup class:

```
public class PopupAudio implements OnClickListener {

    LinearLayout layoutOfPopup;
    PopupWindow popupMessage;
    Button popRecord, popStopRecord, popPlay, popStopPlaying;
    TextView popupText;

    public void popupInit() {
        popRecord.setOnClickListener(this);
        popStopRecord.setOnClickListener(this);
        popPlay.setOnClickListener(this);
        popStopPlaying.setOnClickListener(this);
        popupMessage = new PopupWindow(layoutOfPopup, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        popupMessage.setContentView(layoutOfPopup);
    }

    public void init(Context context) {
        popRecord = new Button(context);
        popRecord.setId(112);
        popStopRecord = new Button(context);
        popPlay = new Button(context);
        popStopPlaying = new Button(context);
        layoutOfPopup = new LinearLayout(context);
        popRecord.setText("REC");
        layoutOfPopup.setOrientation(1);
        layoutOfPopup.addView(popRecord);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(v.getId()) {
        case 112:

            break;
        }
    }

}
```

It is a school project so it is very important. Please help me, I'll be grateful :)

Comment: Do you call on of the **[variations](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html#showAsDropDown(android.view.View))** of `popup.show()` somwhere

Comment: was just about to say, you might be missing your `.show()`. @codeMagic has it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call a method to actually **show** the popup on some event action or whenever you need it. [Here are the different methods from the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html#showAsDropDown(android.view.View))

[Here is one example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19138146/how-to-open-a-popup-at-the-bottom-above-another-view-in-android/19138486#19138486) of using `showAtLocation()`.

`showAsDropDown(View anchor)` may be the simplest depending on your needs. Just pass it the `view` you want it to attach to. Though, the other two give you more flexibility on where it shows.

Comment: I get the view from the activity using this: this.findViewById(R.layout.activity_note)
And I use popupMessage.showAsDropDown(anchor); but it throws me nullpointer exception

Comment: You need to initialize your popupwindow somewhere. You do it in your other class but don't return the view so it's not initialized anywhere. In the tutorial you are following, they do it all in the activity class.